# Parsing and showing HTML audio current time with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, javascript-audio-api

I'm working on a plain JavaScript + HTML audio player and at this time I want to build a interface that show the current time of the audio in the form "MM:SS".
For what I could search the [HTML Audio/Video DOM Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) has only one native function - `audio|video.currentTime` - that return the current audio time in seconds with a large decimal precision.

In order to do this I code:

HTML

```
<audio id='audio' src="http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Canon.mp3" controls></audio>
<div id="timer">00:00</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var audio = document.getElementById('audio'),
      timer = document.getElementById('timer');

var update = setInterval(function() {

  timer.innerHTML = audio.currentTime;
}, 10);
```

I tried a bunch of thing but I could not format the output the way I wanted.
Hope some of you guys can bring some light on this.

[Codepen sample](https://codepen.io/joaosaragossa/pen/grKQmy)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working edited [CodePen](https://codepen.io/stavro510/pen/ONEarP)

Just needed a little math! JS below:

```
var update = setInterval(function() {
      var mins = Math.floor(audio.currentTime / 60);
      var secs = Math.floor(audio.currentTime % 60);
      if (secs < 10) {
        secs = '0' + String(secs);
      }
      timer.innerHTML = mins + ':' + secs;
    }, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most elegent way:

```
var seconds = audio.currentTime % 60;
var minutes = Math.floor(audio.currentTime / 60);

timer.innerHTML = ('0' + minutes).substr(-2) + ':' + ('0' + seconds).substr(-2);
```